# Why do I have to put my mailing address

Tags: steam

When I am redeeming a code on Steam why do I have to put my mailing address? What happens if I put in my address?

Comment: What if I'm on CA

Comment: Please don't edit your question to ask something different.  That's what new questions are for, especially after someone was nice enough to answer it.

Comment: Fine I will wait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They just need to know where you live in order to correctly apply any required taxes to your purchases. Nothing will be sent to you.

http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2780567

https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/622954747302629048/

Comment: Wait, so games on steam requires tax and if I don't have enough money for tax do I have to pay it

Comment: @SuperiorAsian i believe you only have to pay tax if you reside in the state where Valve is located. If you are worried about payments, consider submitting an inquiry to their customer support. They will likely explain it better than anyone else can. However the only information I can find released by them is that its for tax purposes.

Comment: @SuperiorAsian If you buy it you it with your credit card/debit card then they will get the information from the card and charge the tax to the card if it is required as far as I know.

Comment: @SuperiorAsian If your use of Steam is subject to any type of use or sales tax, then Valve may also charge you for those taxes, in addition to the Subscription or other fees published in the Rules of Use. The European Union VAT (“VAT”) tax amounts collected by Valve reflect VAT due on the value of any Software or Subscription. The price (with tax if applicable) will be calculated at check out.

Comment: @SuperiorAsian yes, if they purchase it, they can select it as a gift and send it to you.

Comment: do I need to be friends with that person

Comment: @SuperiorAsian no, they can send it to your email or your steam account.

Comment: if they do, do I need to do anything or just install it right when I receive it

Comment: @SuperiorAsian https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=6262-QXCN-0755